# codeigniter query: how to take all the record from a column in a table when i use sum Select function to get data from another table

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, join

the case is i have this table called journal_type 
id_type | account_no | description | 
--------------------------------------------- 
1           |
1.1               |
bank 
2           |
1.2               |
bank & cash
3           |
1.3               |
sale
4           |
1.4               |
stock
5           |
1.5               |
office tools
6           |
1.6               | payroll

and the second table called journal is something like this 
id_transaction | id_type | debit | date_of_transaction
--------------------------------------------- 
1                      |
1        |
50.00 | 08-22-2018
2                      |
3        |
90.00 | 08-21-2018
3                      |
1        |
80.00 | 08-17-2018

what i do so far is sum the data from second table's debit column based on month(in this case is august) and i want to group it by the id_type. so it would be something like id_type1 = 130.00 and id_type3 = 90.00 
but i want the output is printing all the record from the id_type column in first table and let the other column null when it don't used. maybe the result i want is something like this

id_type | account_no | description | debit
--------------------------------------------- 
1           |
1.1               |
bank            | 130
2           |
1.2               |
bank & cash| 0
3           |
1.3               |
sale             | 90
4           |
1.4               |
stock           | 0
5           |
1.5               |
office tools  |0
6           |
1.6               | payroll         | 0

```
public function get_finance_debitkredit($periode1, $periode2){
  $query = $this->db->select('sum(debit) as debit, journal_type.account_no, journal_type.description, journal.id_type')
          ->from('journal_type')
          ->join('journal', 'journal.id_type = journal_type.id_type', 'left outer')
          ->group_by('journal.id_type')
          ->where('date_of_transaction >=', $periode1)
          ->where('date_of_transaction <=', $periode2)
          ->order_by('journal_type.account_no')
          ->get();
    return $query;  
}
```

but so far what I get is that it's only printed the record data that have the transaction (in this case is the id_type 1 and id_type_3) so only 2 row that appear. can i make all the 6 row of journal_type appear like what i want with some change of the query.
that code is from my model in codeigniter

Answer (score 0):

You first need to create seperate table for that records and then need to left join with that table. Use following query it will give the result you want

```
public function get_finance_debitkredit($periode1, $periode2){
$query = $this->db->select('finl_tbl.debit, journal_type.account_no, journal_type.description, journal_type.id_type')
      ->from('journal_type')
      ->join('(SELECT sum(debit) as debit,id_type FROM journal WHERE date_of_transaction >='.$periode1.' AND date_of_transaction <='.$periode2.' group by id_type) as finl_tbl', 'finl_tbl.id_type = journal_type.id_type', 'left')
      ->order_by('journal_type.account_no')
      ->get();
return $query;  
}
```